# C struct with a pointer to be wrapped in a unique_ptr

Tags: c++, unique-ptr

I have a memory struct as shown below.

```
struct memoryStruct {
    uint8_t* memory;
    size_t size;
};
```

My code requires me to call `free(memory)` at multiple places in my code. To avoid this scenario I am thinking of wrapping it in a `unique_ptr`.

I have the following

```
struct memoryStruct {
    uint8_t* memory;
    size_t size;
};

struct memoryStructDeleter {
    void operator()(memoryStruct* p) const
    {
        free(p);
    }
};
```

How do I initialize m_chunk shown below. I want to allocate a memory of size `using malloc` to memory field and update size accordingly.

```
std::unique_ptr<memoryStruct> m_chunk;
```

Comment: When does `memory` get allocated? Can you replace `uint8_t*` with `unique_ptr<uint8_t[]>` ?

Comment: @jtbandes or just `std::vector<uint8_t>`

Comment: I can't see a good case for dynamically allocating `memoryStruct`. Can you expand on your use case so we can see if you can avoid this altogether?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you cannot change the struct at all (you should, if you can) and you only want to call `malloc` and `free` and not `new` and `delete` (which are superior), you can do the following:

```
struct memoryStructDeleter {
    void operator()(memoryStruct* p) const
    {
        if (p) {
            if (p->memory) {
                 free(p->memory);
            }
            free(p);
        }
    }
};

std::unique_ptr<memoryStruct, memoryStructDeleter> create(size_t s) {
    std::unique_ptr<memoryStruct, memoryStructDeleter> ret(static_cast<memoryStruct*>(malloc(sizeof(memoryStruct))));
    if (!ret) {
        return nullptr;
    }
    ret->memory = static_cast<uint8_t*>(malloc(s * sizeof(uint8_t)));
    if (ret->memory) {
        return ret;
    } else {
        return nullptr;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You would need something like this:

```cpp
struct memoryStruct {
    uint8_t* memory;
    size_t size;
};

struct memoryStructDeleter {
    void operator()(memoryStruct* p) const
    {
        if (p) {
            free(p->memory);
            free(p);
        }
    }
};

...

std::unique_ptr<memoryStruct, memoryStructDeleter> m_chunk( static_cast<memoryStruct*>(std::malloc(sizeof(memoryStruct))) );
if (m_chunk) {
    m_chunk->size = DesiredSize;
    m_chunk->memory = static_cast<uint8_t*>(std::malloc(m_chunk->size));
}
```

Which can be greatly simplified if you get rid of `malloc()` altogether and use `new`/`new[]` or `std::make_unique()` instead:

```cpp
struct memoryStruct {
    std::unique_ptr<uint8_t[]> memory;
    size_t size;

    memoryStruct(size_t asize = 0) : memory(new uint8_t[asize]), size(asize) {}
    // or:
    // memoryStruct(size_t asize = 0) : memory(std::make_unique<uint8_t[]>(asize)), size(asize) {}
};

...

std::unique_ptr<memoryStruct> m_chunk(new memoryStruct(DesiredSize));
// or:
// std::unique_ptr<memoryStruct> m_chunk = std::make_unique<memoryStruct>(DesiredSize);
```

Which can then be simplified even further if you use `std::vector` instead of `std::unique_ptr`:

```cpp
struct memoryStruct {
    std::vector<uint8_t> memory;
    memoryStruct(size_t size = 0) : memory(size) {}
};

...

std::unique_ptr<memoryStruct> m_chunk(new memoryStruct(DesiredSize));
// or:
// std::unique_ptr<memoryStruct> m_chunk = std::make_unique<memoryStruct>(DesiredSize);
```